# C - Reassign pointer inside of struct to pointer outside of struct

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

I have two pointers, each pointing to a different array. One of the pointers is inside of a struct, as follows:

```
typedef struct
{
    int     N;    /* Number of Elements in array */
    double *c;    /* Pointer to an array         */
    /* Other members....  */
} CS;
```

The struct was initialized by:

```
CS->N = n; /* n is an integer of an initially unknown size */
CS->c = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
```

The pointer in the struct, `CS->C`, contains data that I no longer care about.

My other pointer was defined as follows:

```
double *alpha;
alpha = (double *)malloc(CS->N * sizeof(double));
```

I need to replace the contents of `CS->C` with `alpha`. I know I can do something naive like:

```
for (i=0;i<CS->N;i++) /* i is an integer */
    CS->c[i] = alpha[i];
```

I could also use memcpy, like this:

```
memcpy(CS->c,alpha,CS->N * sizeof(double));
```

My understanding is that both of these methods will copy the contents from memory located at `alpha` to the memory occupied by `CS->C`. That being a very expensive operation, it would make more sense to simply change the assignment of `CS->C` to `alpha`.

How can I do this?

I've tried to reassign the pointer by doing like `CS->C = &alpha`, but this gives me the following warning "assignment from incompatible pointer type".

Note: This is using ANSI C89 under full compliance, i.e. the compiler options are: `-Wall -pedantic -ansi`

**Edit 1**
Freeing `CS->c` and assigning it to `alpha` by doing:

```
free(CS->c);
CS->c = alpha;
```

does not work. It causes every entry in `CS->c` to become equal to `0.0` and it results in my program seg faulting.

**Edit 2**
I think I realized why the method suggested in my first edit did not work. `alpha` is a temporary pointer, created and initialized inside of a function, so once that function is exited, the memory occupied by `alpha` is "freed". Since `CS->c` points to that memory, it is also freed. Upon this discovery, I think I will rework my code, such that `alpha` and `CS-c` are initially swapped, such that when they are switched again, the end order will be correct. Thank you all for you valuable input.

Comment: CS->c = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(*CS->c)); // instead of sizeof(double) so the day you'll change your struct it will not break :-)

Comment: How about a simple CS->c=alpha after freeing the old data?

Comment: @JulienPalard No, `CS->c = malloc(n * sizeof(*CS->c));` instead of `CS->c = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(*CS->c));`, since you should not cast the return value of `malloc()`.

Comment: If you love -Wall -ansi -pedantic your should love (as me) -Wextra -Wstrict-prototypes ;-)

Comment: @H2CO3 You're right :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Free the old pointer and assing the new directly. (Not the adress of the new pointer)

> The pointer in the struct, `CS->c`, contains data that I no longer
>   care about.
>
> My other pointer was defined as follows:

```
double *alpha;
alpha = malloc(CS->N * sizeof(double));
```

...

```
free (CS->c);
CS->c = alpha ; alpha=NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the pointer

```
CS->C = alpha;
```

Alpha is a pointer to double, CS->C too, types matches, you simply change the pointer.

/!\ Don't forgot to free the old CS->C ...